# WinForms ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed has no effect

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, progress-bar, marquee

I have a WinForms application which contains a ProgressBar that uses ProgressBarStyle.Marquee. It works fine: I can do some work on a thread and the marquee animates like it's supposed to.

The problem is, changing the ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed doesn't appear to have any impact whatsoever on the animation. I can turn it down to 1 or turn it up to 10,000 and the observed animation speed does not change at all.

I've tried setting it in the Properties panel in Visual Studio as well as setting it in code at runtime. Neither approach has any effect. I've also set a breakpoint and verified that the value is what I expect it to be, and it is, but still the animation speed is not actually affected. It seems like this property is just straight-up being ignored, and the animation speed is coming from somewhere else entirely.

All I can find from Google is "my progress bar doesn't animate at all" which is not the problem I have. Mine animates fine. I just can't seem to change the animation speed at all.

What gives?

(FWIW I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.)

Comment: You need to set [`Style`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Marquee`. Then assign a suitable value to [`MarqueeAnimationSpeed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.marqueeanimationspeed(v=vs.110).aspx). *Since the marquee animation speed is a time period, setting the value to a higher number results in a slower speed and a lower number results in a faster speed.*

Comment: Style is currently set to Marquee. I understand that MarqueeAnimationSpeed is a time period. It doesn't matter what I set it to: the observed animation speed never changes.

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows 10. But in Windows 8.1 it's OK.

Comment: Tested on Windows 10. Works fine. Rebuild solution?

Answer (score 0):

This control is tied to Windows's Visual effects 'Animate control and elements inside windows' configuration.

You can find it in Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Performance -> Visual Effects

It looks like you can't force animation speed if this config is turned on (and it is by default)

[screenshot of configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anAwX.png)